# Magento - hide some of the footer links

Tags: magento

how can I hide some of the footer links if the user is not logged in?

Thank you.

Comment: can you be more specific as to which footer links? Perhaps provide a screenshot?

Comment: I talk about Magento footer links, in my case they are in a cms static block and generated by footer.phtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your local.xml (in your package/design/layout/ folder) you can use the special handle `customer_logged_out`, for example:

```
<customer_logged_out>
   <remove name="name_of_block_to_remove"></remove>
</customer_logged_out>
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a new static block with the links you want to hide if logged in.

Insert it into your CMS page with:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="myfooterlinks.phtml"}}
```

Inside myfooterlinks.phtml would exist:

```
<?php if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()): ?>

Your links here

<?php endif; ?>
```